# Completely remove matching string from HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a website with a second level navigation with a fair whack of divs and styles applied to it. The problem is, there are some pages with no child pages so the subnav is empty and looks a bit odd.

I could not manage to find a simple script to remove html.

This is the code I want to remove:

```
<div class="sub_nav"><div class="track_nav_style_1">
<div class="track_nav_links">
<ul></ul>
</div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "script"? Why are you generating a second level navigation div if there are no child pages at all? It's clumsy to first generate an empty div and then to remove it.

Comment: Thanks mate, the site has several thousand pages, many of which have children pages, many of which don't. We don't have the resources to identify which ones do or don't, and have one html parse file to work with. The clumsy option is the best case for us in this instance as if the script fails to launch, the worst that can happen is an empty grey div appears at the top of the page. The system we have isn't robust and will spit out menu HTML whether there are items to list or not. Also, by script, I mean an onload javascript. Thank you.

Comment: Can you use JS or jQuery to check each `ul` element, and if it's empty, remove the parent?

Comment: @Shomz thanks that sounds like what I want to do, do you know if it can remove all three parent divs?

Comment: @user1038627 You should share some details. How do you load that "onload Javascript"? Why can't you check for this in the program on the server side?

Comment: @user1038627 see below for jQuery script.

Comment: @user1038627 sorry I didn't manage to reply earlier; I see you got the solution and that's the only thing that matters... and remember, there's always a way do to ANYTHING! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really hope I got you right, and if so, I suggest using a simple jQuery script.
Include the following in your `<head>` section.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    google.load('jquery', '1.7.1');
</script>
```

The following script will remove the `<ul>` container if there are no `<li>` below.

```
    if ($('.track_nav_links ul li').length == 0)
        $('.track_nav_links ul').remove();
```

Comment: If you make someone include jQuery, at least offer a jQuery script that is not bloody ineffective.

Comment: @bažmegakapa point taken, foolishly copy-pasted from jquery.com homepage source. Answer now edited to reflect this.

Comment: I'm not talking about the include code, but your code. Why do you run almost the same selector twice? In a bigger DOM, this can become quite expensive. If you're introducing jQuery to someone, try to introduce in a knowledgable way. This code is exactly why some people hate jQuery.

Comment: @mr. kav, thank you, your script works perfectly. I altered it to remove the whole parent div and it worked perfectly first time. You rule!

Comment: @bažmegakapa hi again, I'm not sure I've been trying to introduce jQuery here. I was trying to provide a very simple and straightforward solution to a basic question. I feel that when providing a code example, the example itself should be as self-explanatory as possible, that's why there is the additional stage of iteration/selector usage. The user will take the role making sure the code is most efficient for his situation.  That said, I take your comment on-board and try to continue and do my best at providing more knowledgeable answers :)

Comment: @mr.kav The "user" in most cases just copy-pastes, so ineffective code spreads. Something like `var $list = $('.track_nav_links ul'); if ($list.find('li').length == 0) $list.remove();` is also effective and self-explanatory.

Comment: @bažmegakapa Hey mate :) the code works really well and was easy for me to modify for my site. While I can write HTML and CSS in my sleep, JQuery is a week point for me. The more I use it, the more that changes. No need to be negative, as the answer was spot on and so far has worked flawlessly on all our tests. Thanks again mr. kav ;)

Comment: @user1038627 I was not negative. I pointed out the weaknesses of his solution. You can listen and learn how to write better code, or ignore it. The same happened to me on SO, first I thought everybody is so negative. My code works so it must be good! Later I found out that they are just teaching me and I better listen.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try doing it with css. Something like:

```
.track_nav_links ul{
  padding: 0;
  height: auto;
  /* background styles and others can be applied, but won't be visible unless the list has content */
}

.track_nav_links ul li{
  /* Use the css on these elements to determine height, style etc */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, the div is styled at a set height with borders and a background, so CSS wouldn't work in this instance. But thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a Python script:

import os

```
snippet = """<div class="sub_nav"><div class="track_nav_style_1">
<div class="track_nav_links">
<ul></ul>
</div>
</div></div>"""

def remove_code_snippet_from_file(file_name):
    f = open(file_name, 'r+')
    old_code = f.read()
    f.close()
    f = open(file_name, 'w')
    f.write(old_code.replace(snippet, ''))
    f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for file_name in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        if file_name.endswith('.html'):
            remove_code_snippet_from_file(file_name)
```

Comment: How do you know he uses Python?

Comment: I don't know that he uses Python. Thank you for bringing that point up.

Comment: Hey mate thanks for the response, unfortunately Python is no good to me, but thanks for your time.